# UnauthorizedAccessException trying to access uwp publisher cache after manually adding files

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an app that uses the publisher cache folder. I copied some files into the respective directory to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<publisherId>\Folder` and am now getting an `UnauthorizedAccessException` trying to query the files.

This is what I added to the appx-manifest, at the botton, just before the `</Package>`:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.publisherCacheFolders">
    <PublisherCacheFolders>
      <Folder Name="Folder"/>
    </PublisherCacheFolders>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

However, I am getting an `UnauthorizedAccessException` at the following line:

```
await ApplicationData.Current.GetPublisherCacheFolder("Folder").GetFileAsync(location)
```

The exception details indicate that the exception is thrown from `GetFileAsync` because it is in fact thrown by the internal Awaiter. What am I doing wrong? When I wrote the code last Thursday, everything worked fine. Today, I wanted to demonstrate it and got this exception. Shouldn't the declaration in the appxmanifest be enough or am I missing something?

**Edit:** I just noticed that I also can no longer write to the publisher cache folder. Trying to create a new and empty file `shared.txt`, I also get the same `UnauthorizedAccessException`. Can this be a problem with the publisher certificate? I am using a self-signed test certificate, which I manually installed also for the user and the local machine.

Comment: My guess is it's an integrity-level problem (or other basic ACL problem). You copied the files at Medium IL using Explorer, but the app is at Low IL. I believe the command-line tool `icacls` can tell you this. Basically, the app folders are not supposed to be used by normal users.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Actually I wrote a small program to copy the files for me, because I was too lazy to do that all the time. However, setting the integrity level to low also did not solve the problem. What is the intended way of debugging the contents of a publisher folder?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT ...and why did it work before, then?...

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT As I do not even have a write access anymore, I guess it is not a problem with the ACL, but something seems wrong with my setup, unfortunately, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to make the error message go away. However, the solution is not nice and I would be very thankful if someone had a better one.

1. I created a new app that essentially does the file copying as the desktop app did before, but in a uwp app with the same publisher. Though this is quite painful as you have to ask the user for permission all the time through a folder picker, it does work.
2. I uninstalled the app in question so that Windows deletes the respective publisher folder. Leaving the system with the publisher cache folder created in the explorer or any other desktop program, the app continues to get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`
3. I ran the deployment app to copy the files to the publisher folder only through UWP APIs. During local deployment, Windows would recreate the publisher cache folder such that the app has access to it.
4. I ran the original app. Debugging in mixed mode, I got an `AccessViolationError`, but that one is not passed to managed code, so everything well.