# WindowsAppSDK denies permission to read PublisherCache folder

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-6.0, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

As I am upgrading my **uwp** app to **WindowsAppSDK** and **WinUI3** desktop app, I got this exception of **Permission denied** on **PublisherCacheFolder**. And it was working fine in uwp. I intend to package the app with **msix** so I will still technically upload it to store.

> Just to clarify I do have folder names in package file in Extensions thats how it was working fine in uwp

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41242644/2411960) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by reinstalling the app, dont know why but it had to do something with existing uwp version of the app being overriden with this windowsAppSDK version of the app under same publisher

Comment: doesnt always work very inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while migrating an app from UWP to WinUI3. In my case a found a workaround by using **System.IO.File** to read and write content from Publisher folder and avoid the UnauthorizedAccessException. And of course, I have the folder included the Package manifest Extensions.

```
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.GetPublisherCacheFolder("Folder1");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder.Path, "test.txt"), "test");
var testContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder.Path, "test.txt"));
```

Hope that helps.